# Error reading empty parquet file as pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

Thanks to the suggestion from @TDrabas, I investigated my issue a bit more. Updated my question as below:

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame([[1]])
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','b','c')], names=["column1", "column2", "column3"])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','b','c')], names=["column1", "column2", "column3"])

# narrow down to empty df
df = df.loc[[], []]
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, 'my_table.parquet')

# the following breaks
pd.read_parquet('my_table.parquet')

# the following works fine
table=pq.read_table('my_table.parquet')
table
# pyarrow.Table
# column1: null
# column2: null
# column3: null
# metadata
table.shape
# (0, 3)
```

`pd.read_parquet` gives error

```
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py", line 1071, in <listcomp>
    for level, col_index in zip_longest(
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I found a solution to handle that but is there a more elegant way than that?

```
df = df.loc[[]] # instead of df.loc[[], []]
```

Comment: can you get the column names from the table? then maybe pd.DataFrame(columns=[yourcolumns]). Should just give you an empty dataframe.

Comment: What is your output of `print(pd.__version__)`? I can't reproduce the error

Comment: Are `'my_file.parquet'` and `'my_table.parquet'` the same files? Also, what is the version of pyarrow and pandas you are using?

Comment: @TDrabas sorry yes they are the same file. it was a typo. I just updated my question

Comment: I just tested this and had no issues. Would you mind sharing the info I asked earlier (Python 3.6 seems a bit dated) and how the file was created?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I just did a bit more research and updated my question. @TDrabas would you mind take another look? thank you so much!